# vb.net client object model: view content from sharepoint 2010 wikipage

Tags: client-object-model

On SharePoint 2010 i have many wikipages containing a table. Is it possible to view the content of that page in vb.net using the client object model?

I tried to get the file code using a stream but the text i get is a lot of asp.net code (with the placeholders) but not the html code/content from that page...

```
    Dim fileAlgemeen As SP.File = Nothing
    Dim siteUrl As String = "https://portal.xx.be/sites/kdb"
    Dim ctx As New ClientContext(siteUrl)
    Dim credentials As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential("xx", "xx")
    ctx.Credentials = credentials
    Dim web As Web = ctx.Web
    ctx.Load(web)
    ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Dim relativeUrl As String = "/sites/kdb/596/Algemeen.aspx"
    Dim file As SP.File = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativeUrl)
    ctx.Load(file)
    ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    Dim fileRef = relativeUrl 

    Dim fileInfo As FileInformation = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, fileRef.ToString())

    Using fileInfo.Stream
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fileInfo.Stream)
            Dim line As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
            lbl.Text = line
        End Using
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to *read* and *update* wiki content using SharePoint CSOM (VB.NET)

```
Sub Main()

    Const siteUrl As String = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/kb/"
    Const userName As String = "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
    Const password As String = "password"

    Using ctx = New ClientContext(siteUrl)


        Dim credentials As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential(userName, password)
        ctx.Credentials = credentials

        '1. Read Wiki content 
        Dim wikiFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/kb/Pages/Welcome.aspx")
        Dim wikiItem = wikiFile.ListItemAllFields
        ctx.Load(wikiItem)
        ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Console.WriteLine(wikiItem("PublishingPageContent"))

        '2. Update wiki content
        wikiItem("PublishingPageContent") = "<h1>Welcome to the SharePoint!</h1>"
        wikiItem.Update()
        ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    End Using

End Sub
```

Key Points:

- Wiki content is stored in `List Item` `PublishingPageContent` field
- [File.ListItemAllFields property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.listitemallfields.ASPx) is used to retrieve `List Item`
  associated with `File`

Comment: can you also create a new wiki page by code?

Comment: Sure you can, it sounds like a good question for me. I would recommend to create a new question for it

Comment: [link]http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117081/sp2010-vb-net-client-object-model-add-new-wikipage-to-document-library