# SP2010: Client object model: add new wikipage to document library

Tags: 2010, document-library, client-object-model, wiki-pages, .net

Is it possible to create a new wiki page using the client object model and give it some content ("`<h1>Welcome to the SharePoint!</h1>`")?

I'm using VB.Net

Comment: Yes, You can check the "Example: create Wiki page via CSOM" at the end of blog.http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/11/19/some-tips-and-tricks-of-using-sharepoint-client-object-model-in-powershell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to create Wiki page using SharePoint CSOM

The example below demonstrates how to create wiki page via CSOM (VB.NET version):

```
Sub CreateWikiPage(context As ClientContext, pageName As String, pageContent As String)

    Const templateRedirectionPageMarkup As String = "<%@ Page Inherits=""Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath=""~TemplatePageUrl"" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath=""~masterurl/custom.master"" %>"

    Dim wikiPages = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages")
    context.Load(wikiPages)
    context.ExecuteQuery()

    Dim fileInfo = New FileCreationInformation()
    fileInfo.Url = pageName
    fileInfo.Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(templateRedirectionPageMarkup)
    fileInfo.Overwrite = True

    Dim wikiFile = wikiPages.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo)
    context.Load(wikiFile)
    context.ExecuteQuery()

    Dim wikiPage = wikiFile.ListItemAllFields
    wikiPage("PublishingPageContent") = pageContent
    wikiPage("PublishingPageLayout") = "/_catalogs/masterpage/EnterpriseWiki.aspx, Basic Page"
    wikiPage.Update()
    context.ExecuteQuery()

End Sub
```

> Note: the provided method is intended for creating *enterprise* wiki pages

**Usage**

```
Using ctx = New ClientContext(siteUrl)      
   CreateWikiPage(ctx, "Greetings.aspx", "<H1>Welcome to the SharePoint!</H1>")
End Using
```

### References

[Some tips and tricks of using SharePoint Client Object Model in PowerShell. Part 1](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/11/19/some-tips-and-tricks-of-using-sharepoint-client-object-model-in-powershell/)

---

### How to create a page in Wiki Page Library using CSOM

**For SharePoint 2013**

Use [Utility.CreateWikiPageInContextWeb method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.utilities.utility.createwikipageincontextweb(v=office.15).aspx) to create a page in `Wiki Page Library`:

```
Sub CreateWikiPageInLibrary(context As ClientContext, wikiPageLibraryTitle As String, pageName As String, pageContent As String)

    Dim wikiLibrary = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(wikiPageLibraryTitle)
    context.Load(wikiLibrary.RootFolder)
    context.ExecuteQuery()

    Dim wikiPageInfo As New WikiPageCreationInformation
    wikiPageInfo.WikiHtmlContent = pageContent
    wikiPageInfo.ServerRelativeUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", wikiLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, pageName)
    Dim wikiFile = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.CreateWikiPageInContextWeb(context, wikiPageInfo)
    context.ExecuteQuery()

End Sub
```

**For SharePoint 2010**

```
Sub CreateWikiPageInLibrary(context As ClientContext, wikiPageLibraryTitle As String, pageName As String, pageContent As String)

    Dim wikiLibrary = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(wikiPageLibraryTitle)
    context.Load(wikiLibrary.RootFolder)
    context.ExecuteQuery()


    Dim pageUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", wikiLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, pageName)
    Dim wikiFile = wikiLibrary.RootFolder.Files.AddTemplateFile(pageUrl, TemplateFileType.WikiPage)
    context.Load(wikiFile)
    context.ExecuteQuery()

    Dim wikiPage = wikiFile.ListItemAllFields
    wikiPage("WikiField") = pageContent
    wikiPage.Update()
    context.ExecuteQuery()

End Sub
```

Comment: I got an error: "Column 'PublishingPageLayout' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user" when executing the last line

Comment: Hmm..  are you creating a wiki page under Wiki site?

Comment: Please verify your Pages library whether it contains ootb PublishingPageLayout column

Comment: the page library only contains Wiki Content, Created By,   
Modified By and Checked Out To. The new wiki is created in the list but i can't open it

Comment: btw I had to change "PublishingPageContent" to "WikiField"

Comment: Could you please provide some details, what Site Template are you using.. i cant reproduce it..

Comment: Where can I see that? i didn't created this site

Comment: I have to leave now, get back to you after an hour aprox..

Comment: Okay, i got it, you are creating a wiki page in Wiki Page Library, not a publishing wiki page. The answer has been updated, see the section: How to create a page in Wiki Page Library using CSOM

Comment: WikiPageCreationInformation and Utility.CreateWikiPageInContextWeb doesn't excist. I think it is new in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: The answer has been updated that demonstrates how to create wiki page in SP 2010

Comment: thx, your help is really appreciated! It worked! I accepted your answer but I need one more reputation to upvote it :p.

Comment: Glad this helped you! And no worries about upvoting :)